# Is there a way to return two combined lists from get_queryset instead of just the query set?

Tags: python, django

I am using Django to generate a generic.ListView of objects. I am also using Elastic Search for search results. My question is how can I combine my queryset with an ordered list of JSON objects? `get_queryset` only allows me to return one variable (the queryset) but I need `get_context_data` to be able to access both the queryset and the associated metadata for the search results.
I created a below hack that works but looking for a better solution.

```
def get_queryset(self):
    # just get 2 documents, in my actual code the queryset is generated by a list of IDs
    # from the Elastic Search query
    qs = Document.objects.all()[:2] 
    # create some fake search results, in my actual code I get a similar looking JSON 
    # objects with metadata like result score or highlighted snippets from the search corpus
    fake_results = [
            { 'meta': {
                'highlight': {
                    'title': ['ABC'],
                    'content': ['123', '456'],
                    }
                }
            },
            { 'meta': {
                'highlight': {
                    'content': ['789'],
                    }
                }
            }
            ]

    # this is a hack (i think) but need to merge the metadata from search results into the queryset object                
    for doc, result in zip(qs, fake_results): 
        if 'highlight' in result['meta']:
            doc.snippet = result['meta']['highlight']

    return qs

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    """ do stuff with the modified queryset """
```

Comment: Personally I don't see any issue with your solution; in general it's not 'hacky' to seriously override the methods of generic class based views, it's actually encouraged, and often necessary. Note that you can perform additional queries inside get_context_data as well, if you want more stuff to package into your context beyond what get_queryset is returning. You can do your sorting logic in either method, whatever works! zip() and chain() are both useful for packaging varied objects into the final queryset list -- chain is particularly useful if you want objects of more than one type.

Answer (score 0):

You can return any iterable from the get_queryset. You can return zip(qs, fake_results), but you should just unpack it properly.

Comment: This becomes a problem if the queryset is going to be paginated (by Paginator) or re-sorted (by Django Tables plugin). I use both so that’s why I still wanted to return a queryset object.